# Search for a deleted table's reference id in all tables, rows and columns of a DB

Tags: magento2, database, foreign-key-constraint, custom-table

I had copied the table structure of table 'url_rewrite' and created a new table named 'url_rewrite_new' with empty data in my Magento 2 store DB, also renamed the 'url_rewrite' table. Then I ran magento commands and the entries were added in table 'url_rewrite_new'.

Then I deleted the new table 'url_rewrite_new' and restored old table 'url_rewrite' in DB.

But now I am getting the reference id of that deleted table 'url_rewrite_new'.

How could I get Reference ID and remove that?

Comment: did you run reindexer command?

Comment: Yes I had done reindexing.